# Is there any way for javascript to get packets of links to all tags on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I know all the resources requested by the current site can be seen in **F12->Network**.

Is there any way for javascript to get packets of links to all tags on a webpage?

I am currently writing a browser plug-in to achieve this.

Here is an example :

```
    <img src="http://192.168.1.104:8081/img/nanachi.gif"/>    //  example 1

    <img src='http://192.168.1.104:8082/hello.php' hidden>    //  example 2
```

[image: F12->Network]

I am trying to distinguish the difference between **example 1** and **example 2** through the packet.

There is a **window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")** method found, but it seems to only intercept the **example 1**, the **example 2** abnormal method using img tag seems to have no way to find it.  In addition, this function has no way to display the content of the package of this resource.

Comment: What do you mean by "packet", exactly? None of my browsers' dev-tools network tools show any detail below HTTP-level (i.e. _no raw IP or Ethernet packets or frames_)

Comment: I updated the picture in the question.  Isn't this a packet? In the header, I see request, response, Request Method, Status Code...etc

Comment: Noi that's not a packet, you're looking at HTTP protocol messages (requests and responses, and websocket+SSE message-swapping) - that's all at the top of the TCP/IP-model + OSI-model: the application-layer. Whereas the things called packets aren't until you get to the IP layer, which is far deeper than Devtools Network will go (...for now).